# Scala - Change Dataset type

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark

```
case class ACase( name: String)
case class BCase( name: String, num: Int)
```

I have ACase's dataset and would like to change it as BCase type with adding column. Here is my try.

```
def makeBCase( aCase: ACase, num: Int) : BCase = {
    BCase( aCase.name, num)
}
def change( aDS: Dataset[ACase]): Dataset[BCase] = {
    val bDS = aDS.map { a => 
        makeBCase( a, 123)
    }
    ....
    bDS // error - type mismatch; required : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ACase]
}
```

How can I change Its type?

Comment: Pasting the complete compile error would help

Comment: `makeBCase()` appears to return `BCase`, not `DataSet[BCase]`.

Comment: It's return Bcase. sorry for mis-typo.

Comment: 1st argument to `makeBCase()` is supposed to be type `ACase` but you're invoking it with `Dataset[ACase]`.  Typo?

Comment: yes it was too. sorry.

Comment: your code is running fine for me using Spark 2.0.1 and Scala 2.11.8

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I need double check for my real code.